# setting default swiping tab based on time/date in android

Tags: android, tabs, calendar

I have ten swiping tab in one of my activity in android,i named them from tab 1 to tab 10. I want to set default tab for every day

- like suppose if my **tab 4** is of day **15th Nov 2015** than i want to set **tab 4** as default tab for **that day** and change default tab to **tab 5** for **next day**.

  any possible solution to this..please share..thank you

Answer (score 0):

IF you're using a `ViewPager` then it's as simple as calling [`setCurrentItem(int item)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int%29) or [`setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int,%20boolean%29) on the `ViewPager`

> **public void setCurrentItem (int item)**
>
> Set the currently selected page. If the ViewPager has already been through its first layout with its current adapter there will be a smooth animated transition between the current item and the specified item.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> item - Item index to select
>
> **public void setCurrentItem (int item, boolean smoothScroll)**
>
> Set the currently selected page.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> item - Item index to select
>
> smoothScroll - True to smoothly scroll to the new item, false to transition immediately

Comment: yes i am using page viewPager..can u please give more detail??

Comment: More details added from the provided links but it looks like you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Its done.
i just used this way.

```
 try {
        String day1 = "12-Nov-2015 12:04 PM";
        SimpleDateFormat formater1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a");
        Date date1 = formater1.parse(day1); // You will need try/catch around this
        long millis1 = date1.getTime();

        String day2 = "12-Nov-2015 12:05 PM";
        SimpleDateFormat formater2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a");
        Date date2 = formater2.parse(day2); // You will need try/catch around this
        long millis2 = date2.getTime();
   if((currentTime>=millis1) &&(currentTime<millis2)) {
       Toast.makeText(this,"in 1st",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(5, false);


        }
        if(currentTime>=millis2) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"in 2nd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(7, false);

        }



    } catch (ParseException e) {

        //Handle exception here, most of the time you will just log it.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```